# Match a string containing a comma (eg 1,5)

Tags: java, regex

i want to check if the string i take from a Textfield
has a comma, in order to drop it and ask for a new value with dot.

i try to use

```
  textTestAr.trim().matches("^[,]+$")
```

but nothing happens, while this

```
        ^[1-9,]+$
```

does the trick, but also matches numbers like 1.

Comment: What's wrong with `matches(",")`?

Comment: @djechlin that `matches` requires to match the entire string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caret `^` matches the beginning of the text. `[,]+` matches an arbitrary number of commas. What you need is something to ignore everything before and after the item you are looking for:

```
^.*[,].*$
```

The dot matches any character except newline. `*` is repetition (0 -- any number). The `$` matches the end of text.

Note that trimming the string is unnecessary here.

Comment: what is the use of $ here as you explained other elements.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to force regular expressions on this problem. A simple `textTestAr.indexOf(',')` will do.

Comment: I disagree. Better master and stick this one necessary tool than ever fuddle with `indexOf` and friends.

Comment: @user946850 A true master wields all the available instruments with equal grace. If this was ruby or perl, then it would be idiomatic to handle everything with regexps, but in Java regex is not a first-class citizen.

Comment: What do you do if the next requirement to the code is to check if it is made only of digits and one dot? Or if you want to check also for other characters? Or... Compare the effort to change the regular expression with the alternative: First use the "simple" tool (what happens again if no match is found? -1? Exception? Let's look up the API...) just to discover that you need "the" tool anyway.

Comment: @user946850 And what do you do if the next requirement is to parse a recursive structure?

Comment: I plug my regex into a context-free parser generator and start from there. What do you do?

Comment: @user946850 Pretty much the same as you, obviously. If I didn't need the regex before, I sure won't need it with the parser.

Comment: Let me explain my passion about this. I once had to work through Java code that made extensive use of the idioms suggested here to parse HTML output. Somebody else's code, apparently he or she didn't know to use regular expression (or a HTML library, for that matter). Regexp is, along with version control, one of the "must knows" if you do text processing -- better start early and with simple examples.

Comment: @user946850 If you have the misfortune to maintain code that parses HTML either by hardcoding regexps or `indexOf`s and friends, you are in about the same amount of trouble. StackOverflow is already chock-full of horror stories about naive users trying to work through HTML using "the tool"---because it is the only tool they know.

Comment: Anyway, I guess you have already conceded that one uses the right tool for the right job (and definitely does **not** use regexps as "the tool"), which is the point you have disagreed with at the outset.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [String#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of regex here.

Answer (score 4):

Just do 
`if(textTestAr.contains(",")) System.out.println("It does!");`

Answer (score 3):

just do `textTestAr.contains(",")`

Answer (score 2):

The first one asserts that the whole string is made up of commas only. The second one asserts that the string is made up of digits (other than `0`) and commas, but doesn't require a specific one of them. You could use this:

```
.*,.*
```

Note that you don't need `^...$` when using `matches` (because they are implicit). But a simple `indexOf` solution as Marko's or yentup's is better anyway.

Comment: Easy and Fair solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't need regex for that:

```
textTestAr.trim().replace(',','.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public  boolean hasComma(String string) {
    if ( string.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wait, this wasn't javascript? O_O

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna get straight to answering this with Regex,

```
/,/
```

Put one or a combination of alphabets, symbols, or numbers inside of `//` and It will try to match it specifically.